# Tomcat failing to startup

Tags: java, tomcat, java-8, java-7

A few days ago when I turned the computer on, I tried to start up tomcat and got a surprise for the first time since I deal with software development.

The exact error message is:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.9"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.9"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.9\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.9\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.9\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not find agent library D:\Program in absolute path, with error: Can't find dependent libraries
```

and I cannot get the point of it, nor find any info about this in google, trying with 3 different versions of tomcat 7.0.8, 8.0.5, 8.0.9, with all is the same situation. When I saw this I thought JDK is outdated because I had a few versions of it, then I removed all JDKs and JREs from PC and installed only the last one 8u45, but without any luck. Can somebody point me in the right direction?

The output with `echo`

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   "C:\Users\Denees\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.1\apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base"
Using CATALINA_HOME:   "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.15"
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: "C:\Users\Denees\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.1\apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base\temp"
Using JRE_HOME:        "C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_45"
Using CLASSPATH:       "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.15\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.15\bin\tomcat-juli.jar"
"C:\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java.exe" -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="localhost|127.0.0.1|Denees" -Drebel.env.ide.plugin.version=6.2.0.1 -Drebel.env.ide.version=8.0.2 -Drebel.env.ide.product=netbeans -Drebel.env.ide=netbeans -Drebel.base=C:\Users\Denees\.jrebel -Drebel.notification.url=http://localhost:57212 -agentpath:D:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.1\java2\griffin\lib\jrebel64.dll -Djava.util.logging.config.file="C:\Users\Denees\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.1\apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base\conf\logging.properties" -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager   -Djava.endorsed.dirs="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.15\endorsed" -classpath "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.15\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.15\bin\tomcat-juli.jar" -Dcatalina.base="C:\Users\Denees\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.1\apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base" -Dcatalina.home="C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 8.0.15" -Djava.io.tmpdir="C:\Users\Denees\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0.1\apache-tomcat-8.0.15.0_base\temp" org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap  start
```

Comment: Cannot understand what it means

Comment: Are you sure you have a standard tomcat? I suggest using zip standalone version of tomcat.

Comment: Yes it's standart, downloaded from archive

Comment: check your JAVA_OPTS variable or catalina startup.bat script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an error caused by an invalid JVM command-line parameter.  Here's one way to reproduce it:

```
C:\>java -agentpath:D:\Program Files\blahblah
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not find agent library D:\Program in absolute path, with error: Can't find dependent libraries
```

Check Tomcat's Java options.  Run `%CATALINA_HOME%\bin\tomcat8w.exe` as administrator, navigate to the Java tab and take a look at the Java Options.  If the value of `-agentpath` has spaces in it, enclose the value in double quotes.

If you can't find any such argument in Tomcat's startup, check the configuration of your Tomcat server in NetBeans.  Go to Window > Servers, choose your server in the list on the left and click the Platform tab.  If the 'VM Options' field contains a value for the `-agentpath` parameter, and this value has spaces in it, ensure this value is enclosed in double-quote characters.

The `-agentpath` parameter is also used if you start Tomcat in Profile Mode.  Here's the full command-line I saw used to start Tomcat in Profile Mode in NetBeans 8.0.2, captured with the help of Sysinternals Process Explorer, and formatted for readability:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\bin\java.exe"   
  -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts="localhost|127.0.0.1|Stalactite"
  -agentpath:"C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\profiler\lib\deployed\jdk16\windows-amd64\profilerinterface.dll=C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.2\profiler\lib",5140
  -Dnbprofiler.agentid=1145099082
  -Djava.util.logging.config.file="C:\Apache\Tomcat8.0.12\conf\logging.properties"
  -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
  -Djava.endorsed.dirs="C:\Apache\Tomcat8.0.12\endorsed"
  -classpath "C:\Apache\Tomcat8.0.12\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Apache\Tomcat8.0.12\bin\tomcat-juli.jar" 
  -Dcatalina.base="C:\Apache\Tomcat8.0.12"
  -Dcatalina.home="C:\Apache\Tomcat8.0.12"
  -Djava.io.tmpdir="C:\Apache\Tomcat8.0.12\temp"
  org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
```

It's possible that you are using an old version of NetBeans, which might be generating an invalid value for the `-agentpath` parameter.

Failing all of the above, you will need to find out exactly what the command line being used to start Java is.  To do this, edit `catalina.bat` (`C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.9\bin\catalina.bat`) in a text editor.  Towards the bottom are four lines all beginning with `%_EXECJAVA%`.  Take a copy of each line, paste it immediately above and add `echo` to the front of it.  So instead of it looking something like the following (I've abbreviated the `%_EXECJAVA%` lines for clarity):

```
if not "%JPDA%" == "" goto doJpda
if not "%SECURITY_POLICY_FILE%" == "" goto doSecurity
%_EXECJAVA% %JAVA_OPTS% %CATALINA_OPTS% %DEBUG_OPTS% ...
goto end
:doSecurity
%_EXECJAVA% %JAVA_OPTS% %CATALINA_OPTS% %DEBUG_OPTS% ...
goto end
:doJpda
if not "%SECURITY_POLICY_FILE%" == "" goto doSecurityJpda
%_EXECJAVA% %JAVA_OPTS% %CATALINA_OPTS% %JPDA_OPTS% %DEBUG_OPTS% ...
goto end
:doSecurityJpda
%_EXECJAVA% %JAVA_OPTS% %CATALINA_OPTS% %JPDA_OPTS% %DEBUG_OPTS% ...
goto end
```

it should look like

```
if not "%JPDA%" == "" goto doJpda
if not "%SECURITY_POLICY_FILE%" == "" goto doSecurity
echo %_EXECJAVA% %JAVA_OPTS% %CATALINA_OPTS% %DEBUG_OPTS% ...
%_EXECJAVA% %JAVA_OPTS% %CATALINA_OPTS% %DEBUG_OPTS% ...
goto end
:doSecurity
echo %_EXECJAVA% %JAVA_OPTS% %CATALINA_OPTS% %DEBUG_OPTS% ...
%_EXECJAVA% %JAVA_OPTS% %CATALINA_OPTS% %DEBUG_OPTS% ...
goto end
:doJpda
if not "%SECURITY_POLICY_FILE%" == "" goto doSecurityJpda
echo %_EXECJAVA% %JAVA_OPTS% %CATALINA_OPTS% %JPDA_OPTS% %DEBUG_OPTS% ...
%_EXECJAVA% %JAVA_OPTS% %CATALINA_OPTS% %JPDA_OPTS% %DEBUG_OPTS% ...
goto end
:doSecurityJpda
echo %_EXECJAVA% %JAVA_OPTS% %CATALINA_OPTS% %JPDA_OPTS% %DEBUG_OPTS% ...
%_EXECJAVA% %JAVA_OPTS% %CATALINA_OPTS% %JPDA_OPTS% %DEBUG_OPTS% ...
goto end
```

Then, when you start Tomcat, you should see the full command line being run to start Java.  This should appear in the NetBeans log window, immediately below the line that begins `Using CLASSPATH:`.

Now that you've done this and got the output, I can see quite quickly that the problem is caused by the following part of the command line.

```
-agentpath:D:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.1\java2\griffin\lib\jrebel64.dll
```

So you're using JRebel.

I'm not using JRebel, and as I have no social media accounts I can't even register for a trial of it.  All I can do is install the JRebel NetBeans plugin and have a look through the various options.

If you're running Tomcat as a remote server, then there is an error in the setup instructions on the Startup tab of the JRebel plugin's options (Tools > Options > JRebel > Startup).  Line 3 of the `catalina-jrebel.bat` file you are asked to create is as follows:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-javaagent:%REBEL_HOME%\jrebel.jar -Drebel.remoting_plugin=true %JAVA_OPTS%
```

This is of course wrong if your `REBEL_HOME` environment variable contains a space in it, as it appears to do on your machine.  The third line of the above batch script should contain quotes around the value of the `-javaagent` parameter, i.e.:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-javaagent:"%REBEL_HOME%\jrebel.jar" -Drebel.remoting_plugin=true %JAVA_OPTS%
```

If you're starting Tomcat through the IDE, JRebel is supposed to set up the server automatically.  If this is what you are doing and things still aren't working for you then I would seek support from ZeroTurnaround, as this is a JRebel issue.

Incidentally, on your machine, it seems the `REBEL_HOME` environment variable is pointing to somewhere under `D:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.0.1` - I thought you said you have NetBeans 8.0.2 installed?

Finally, as a last resort, try reinstalling NetBeans into a folder that doesn't contain any spaces in it.

Comment: cannot find any `agentpath` field or parameter there

Comment: @Denees: in that case, can you check the configuration of your NetBeans server (see my updated answer)?

Comment: the only parameters that I have there `-Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=256m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m`

Comment: @Denees: which version of NetBeans are you using?  And are you starting Tomcat in Profile Mode?

Comment: I was using 8.0.2 for a few months already, none of the problems was before

Comment: @Denees: I'm afraid I can't reproduce your issue with a newly-installed copy of NetBeans 8.0.2.   Sorry to have to ask you to do this, but could you try reinstalling NetBeans?

Comment: Have you tried deleting and recreating the server in NetBeans?  Are you using a custom startup script to run Tomcat, and if so, what is in this script?  Have you checked your environment variables (in particular `JAVA_OPTS`) to check that there is no `-agentpath` parameter being added?  (Sorry but I am beginning to run out of ideas.)

Comment: Yeah mate, I've checked all this things, and btw I have reinstalled and readed all tomcat several times, I am starting tomcat just from NetBeans. I tried a standalone tomcat installer like tcat from MuleSoft and it's the same situation.

Comment: @Denees: I've edited my answer to include instructions on how to find the exact command line being used to start Java.  That should hopefully show up the rogue command-line parameter that is causing your problems.  Please edit your question to include the command-line that now gets shown in the NetBeans log window.  If that doesn't help then I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @Denees: it seems your problem is with JRebel, which I didn't know you were using until I saw your command line.  As far as I can tell, your JRebel configuration is broken.  I've edited my answer to include some further notes on tracking down the problem.

Comment: thanks mate, for your help and patience, I am using NetBeans 8.0.2, I have updated from 8.0.1, I don't know why NetBeans isn't changing this numbers. I will mark your answer as accepted. Have a nice day.

Answer (score -1):

You should put "C:\Program Files" in quotes or better, install tomcat to a folder without spaces in its name.

Comment: But tomcat is installed in C:\